# Flask imports wrong css

Tags: python, css, flask, pycharm

I'm struggeling with this problem now for hours and can't find the problem. I'm building a flask application for a school project and in my static folder, I made a folder css with a file **style.css**. But when I run the project it usses a completely different stylesheet which is not even linked to my file and it even isn't in my project.

Do any of you have a solution for this.

It would be verry helpfull

Thanks in advance

*CSS in flask project*
[image]

*CSS file that my browser loads*

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you cleared your browser cache(Ctrl+Shift+R) and deleted all the pyc files?

Comment: create an inner folder with the name of static and place all your static files here. Remove your browser cache and try again.